# Is there a mode in python where upon exceptions, python just prints the exception message and executes the next line anyways?

Tags: python, exception

Is there a mode in python that is the equivalent of wrapping every single line with a print out of the exception message like this:

```
try:
    line_of_code()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Two use cases I have for this are making updates to a script and developing a script. Say I accidentally botched a print statement on line 302, say `"{0}{}".format("this throws","an exception")` I still want the rest of the code that has nothing to do with line 302 to continue to run. That way, I get the information I need to fix line 302, as well as get the script to execute and give me the end result I wanting, without having to run again and wait again.

Comment: Python does not allow this. Most languages with termination-model exceptions and true nonlocal exceptions (which is almost every current language with exceptions except a few Lisps) don't allow it. Not just because it would be a pain to implement, but also because, in a typical program, failing one line of code is going to mean a cascade of `UnboundLocalError`s and `AttributeErrors` and other exceptions—or, worse, it could easily lead to you ending up with corrupt data—not to mention that it means that more distant exception handlers don't get to fire.

Comment: Ignoring an error and just continuing on the next line is considered one of the most horrible features of JavaScript for many reasons. And no, there's no JavaScript mode in Python. You will have to fix your code.

Comment: I realize there are a thousand reasons why it may be a bad idea. Showing an example of that doesn’t mean there isn’t a use for it. There are a couple very niche reasons why it may be a good idea. Fuckit is great and worked for my use case. Thanks

Comment: Also as a sidepoint, this is similar behavior to mathematica, ipython, and jupyter notebook. Actually i would be doing this in jupyter notebook, but there are a couple reasons I can’t.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't have any javascript experience, but I have a lot of bash experience, and it's also one of my favorite features of a bash script: one bad line won't tank the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not allow this. In fact, I can't think of any mainstream current language with termination-model exceptions and true nonlocal exceptions (and almost all current languages except some Lisps that have exceptions have termination-model, true nonlocal exceptions) that does.

Why? Well, in a typical program, failing one line of code is going to mean a cascade of `UnboundLocalError`s and `AttributeErrors` and other exceptions—and, worse, it could easily lead to you ending up with corrupt data.

Consider this code:

```
req = request.get(url)
page = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for div in soup.findall('div'):
    print(div.attrs)
```

If you just ignored the 302 error, what do you think would happen? Something like this:

```
UnboundLocalError('req')
AttributeError('text')
UnboundLocalError('page')
TypeError(somewhere deep inside bs4 doing stuff to page)
UnboundLocalError('soup')
AttributeError('findall')
TypeError(iterating the non-existent result)
```

Would that actually be useful?

What if, at the end of all that, you tried this:

```
rows = <something_parsed_from_soup>
with open('stuff.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows.extend(csv.reader(f))
with open('stuff.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)
```

Now you've just erased `stuff.csv` by ignoring the exception.

---

Of course you can hack your way around it with nasty bytecode- or AST-level hacks to insert implicit `try`/`except` around every statement (or every top-level expression, or whatever level you want).

The [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) library (inspired by a similar library for JavaScript) may do what you want—or, if not, it may serve as sample code to build what you want.

> #### The Python Error Steamroller
>
> FuckIt.py uses state-of-the-art technology to make sure your Python code runs
>   whether it has any right to or not. Some code has an error? Fuck it.
>
> ### Technology
>
> FuckIt.py uses a combination of dynamic compilation, Abstract Syntax Tree rewriting, live call stack modification, and love to get rid of all those pesky errors that make programming *so hard*.

If the name of the library, or the general tone of its docs, sours you on the idea of using it… well, that's probably a good thing.

Comment: @SwimBikeRun But Jupyter, IPython, and the REPL _don’t_ do that. They raise the exception, canceling not just any function you happened to be in, but even the top-level compound statement, and display a complete traceback.

Comment: only within the line or block. They don’t wipe the active memory.

Comment: @SwimBikeRun I don’t know what you mean by “wipe the active memory”, but any scopes that are exited by the exception (e.g., if you called a function and the exception happened inside that function) are dead except for the traceback object, just as they are in any scopes exited by an exception while running a script.